# Parallel computing, which alternative to tidyr::complete in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, parallel-processing, multidplyr

I am trying to parallelise a pipe.
In the pipe there is a tidyr command ("tidyr::complete"). This breaks down the code once run in parallel, as the object class is not recognised.

Is there an alternative in dplyr to complete?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)


test <- tibble(year=c(1,2,3,4,5,5,1,4,5),
               var_1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), 
               var_2=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3), 
               var_3=c(0,5,NA,15,20,NA,1,NA,NA))

max_year <- max(test$year,na.rm = T)
min_year <- min(test$year,na.rm = T)
```

**SERIAL**

```
test_serial <- test %>% 
  group_by(var_1,var_2) %>% 
  complete(var_1, year = seq(min_year,max_year)) %>%
  mutate(
    var_3 = na.approx(var_3,na.rm = FALSE),
    var_3 = if(all(is.na(var_3))) NA else na.spline(var_3,na.rm = FALSE))
```

**PARALLEL** (THIS FAILS)

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/multidplyr")
library(multidplyr)

cl <- new_cluster(2)
cluster_copy(cl, c("test","max_year","min_year"))
cluster_library(cl, c("dplyr","tidyr","zoo"))

test_parallel <- test %>% group_by(var_1,var_2) %>% partition(cl)
test_parallel <- test_parallel %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(var_1,var_2) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(var_1, year = seq(min_year,max_year)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    var_3 = na.approx(var_3,na.rm = FALSE),
    var_3 = if(all(is.na(var_3))) NA else na.spline(var_3,na.rm = FALSE)) %>% 
  collect()
```

This is the error message

```
Error in UseMethod("complete_") : 
  no applicable method for 'complete_' applied to an object of class "multidplyr_party_df"
```

Answer (score 11):

Multidplyr allows you to :

1. split the data up using `partition()`
2. process each partition on a dedicated node
3. `collect()` the results

All data processing tasks are not suitable for the previous workflow.

In particular, `complete` needs to know **all the possible values in the input data** in order to create the missing rows, which means that this operation **as a whole** can't be split, that's why no applicable method is available.

In the example you provide, each node would receive a single `var_1, var_2` pair without knowing what the other nodes got, which doesn't allow to achieve the expected result in parallel.

However, as you already know that `year = seq(min_year,max_year)`, you could parallelize the `complete` task for this variable only, splitting tasks by `var_1`, for example with the `furrr` package:

```
library(furrr)
plan(multiprocess)
test_parallel <- test %>% 
  group_by(var_1,var_2) %>% 
  complete(var_1) %>% split(.$var_1) %>% 
  furrr::future_map(~{
    complete(.x, year = seq(min_year,max_year)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        var_3 = na.approx(var_3,na.rm = FALSE),
        var_3 = if(all(is.na(var_3))) NA else na.spline(var_3,na.rm = FALSE)) 
    }) %>% bind_rows()

> identical(c(test_serial$var_1,test_serial$var_2,test_serial$var_3,test_serial$year),
+           c(test_parallel$var_1,test_parallel$var_2,test_parallel$var_3,test_parallel$year))
[1] TRUE
```

To be tested on a larger dataset to measure potential [performance](https://github.com/tidyverse/multidplyr/blob/master/vignettes/multidplyr.md#performance) improvements.

Comment: But, were I able to assign to each node a whole group to complete (say var_1), then will I be able to use complete?

Comment: I got the following warning:

#Warning message: [ONE-TIME WARNING] Forked processing ('multicore') is disabled in future (>= 1.13.0) when running R from RStudio, because it is considered unstable. Because of this, plan("multicore") will fall back to plan("sequential"), and plan("multiprocess") will fall back to plan("multisession") - not plan("multicore") as in the past. For more details, how to control forked processing or not, and how to silence this warning in future R sessions, see ?future::supportsMulticore

Comment: As proof, system.time() revealed that the furrr solution was 4X slower than the standard one

Comment: Multitasking is most of the time slower on an small example dataset because you need to open tasks, transmit the data to them and collect the result back, which for 15 rows takes much more time than processing the data directly, see my last sentence ;-)